# Plot Multiple Y axis + 'hue' scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot, relplot

Dataframe

```
df
Sample Type   y1   y2   y3  y4
S1     H     1000  135  220  171
S2     H     2900  1560 890  194
S3     P     678   350  127  255
S4     P     179   510  154  275
```

I want to plot `y1`, `y2`, `y3`, `y4` vs `Sample` scatterplot with hue as `Type`.

Is there any way to do it in Seaborn?

Answer (score 5):

Since, you want just one plot you can use [`sns.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

#plotting
df1 = df.melt(['Type','Sample'])
sns.scatterplot(data=df1, x="Sample", y="value",hue="Sample",style="Type")
plt.show()
```

[image]

In case you want multiple scatter plots, you can use [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot):

```
#some preprocessing
df1 = df.melt(['Type','Sample'])
#plotting
sns.relplot(data=df1, x="Sample", y="value", hue="Type", col="variable", height=2, aspect=1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In case, you want 2x2 grid :

```
df1 = df.melt(['Type','Sample'])
#plotting
sns.relplot(data=df1, x="Sample", y="value", hue="Type", col="variable",col_wrap=2, height=2,   aspect=1.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In case, you want 1x4 grid :

```
df1 = df.melt(['Type','Sample'])
#plotting
sns.relplot(data=df1, x="Sample", y="value", hue="Type", col="variable",col_wrap=1, height=2,   aspect=1.5)
plt.show()
```